# Why are my glyphicons disappearing when I resize my page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm currently using Bootstrap v3.2.0. When I shrink my page down my glyphicons disappear. I tried downloading new fonts from this site and setting them to a percentage, but no luck. Little help anyone?

Comment: Showeth the code to meh. But seriously, let's see your code that you have tried.

Comment: What OS(es) and browser(s) is this happening on? Does it still happen if you use http://www.bootstrapcdn.com ?

Comment: It's bootstrap out of the box and it happens in all browsers.

<style>
.glyphicon-fast-backward:before {
  content: "\e070";
}</style>

 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>